# Specman e: How a sequence should be started when gen_and_start_main constrained to FALSE?

Tags: specman, e

I've disabled automatic start of `MAIN sequence`, so I can control my sequences flow:

```
extend my_driver {
    keep soft gen_and_start_main == FALSE;   
};
```

But, I don't find a way to start the sequence not-automatically, since I get compilation error, e.g. the code:

```
some_tcm()@clock is {
    // some logic
    start sys.my_agent.my_driver.main_sequence.body();
};
```

Causes an error:

```
cannot call method - object is NULL
```

How the sequence should be started not-automatically, when `gen_and_start_main` field is constrained to `FALSE`?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you have a look in the Cadence documentation? Search for "Creating and Using Sequences".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a sequence can be done using their start_squence() method.
you have generate the sequence, and then start it -

```
    gen sys.my_agent.my_drive.main_sequence keeping {
        .driver == sys.my_agent.my_drive;
    };

    sys.my_agent.my_drive.main_sequence.start_sequence();
```